# Problem with a list in the form of [(key, [..]) ; ...]

Tags: ocaml

I'm trying to learn OCaml since I'm new to the language and I stumbled across this problem where I can't seem to find a way to see, in a function where I need to merge 2 kinds of these lists, if there is already an element with a key, and if so how to join the elements that come after. Would appreciate any guidance.

For example if I have:

```
l1: [(k, [e]); (ka, [])]
l2: [(k, [f; g])]
```

How can I end up with:

```
fl: [(k, [e; f; g]); (ka, [])]
```

Basically, how can I filter the key `k` from both lists while making their elements combine.

Comment: To get a more direct answer that is also useful to the community, you should add more information to your question, show what you have tried, what didn't work, and what is your problem. Questions such as "I have a problem" that do not actually show any effort and do not really describe the problem (other than stating that you have a problem) rarely get useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, using lists as mappings is a bad idea. It is much better to use dedicated data structures such as maps and hash tables.

Answering your question directly, you can concatenate two lists using the `(@)` operator, e.g.,

```
# [1;2;3] @ [4;5;6];;
              
- : int list = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6]
```

If you don't want repetitive elements when you merge then, and I feel like I repeat myself, it is bad to use lists for sets, it is better to use dedicated data structures such as sets and hash sets. But if you want to continue, then you can merge two lists without repetitions by checking if an element is already in the list before prepending to it. Easy to implement but hard to run, in a sense that it takes quadratic time to merge two lists this way.

If you still want to stick with the list of pairs, then you will find that the [List.assoc](https://ocaml.org/api/List.html#VALassoc) function is useful, as it finds a value by key. The overall algorithm would be, *given two lists, `xs` and `ys`, fold over elements of `ys` using `xs` as the initial value `acc`, and for each `(ky,y)` in `ys` if `ky` is already in `acc`, find the associated with `ky` value `x` and remove (`List.remove_assoc`) it, then merge `x` and `y` and prepend the merged value with the `acc` list, otherwise (if it is not in acc) just prepend `(ky,y) to` acc`*. Note that this algorithm doesn't preserve order, so if it matters you need something more complex. Also, if your keys are sorted you can make it a little bit more efficient and easier to implement.

Comment: Thank you for the input, but I don't really care about the time complexity of it right now, just want to try and do it this way. My question was how to check, in a similar list structure as the one I said, if there is already an element with the same key in the other list.

Answer (score 0):

There are functions in the standard OCaml library for dealing with lists of pairs where the first element of each pair is a key. You will find them described here: https://ocaml.org/releases/4.12/api/List.html under **Association lists**.

I will repeat what @ivg says. This is not how you want to solve your problem if you have more than just a few pairs to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Therer absolutely are more efficient ways to accomplish this, but let's break this down into distinct steps working on association lists.

**Step 1:** Combine the two lists into one list. Easy. We just use the `@` operator.

```
# let merge lst1 lst2 =
    let combined = lst1 @ lst2 in
    combined;;
val merge : 'a list -> 'a list -> 'a list = <fun>
# merge [(1, [0]); (3, [6; 7])] [(1, [2])];;
- : (int * int list) list = [(1, [0]); (3, [6; 7]); (1, [2])]
```

**Step2:** Sort that list based on the first element. Let's define a `sort_by` function to make this easier.

```
# let merge lst1 lst2 =
    let combined = lst1 @ lst2 in
    let sort_by f lst = List.sort (fun a b -> compare (f a) (f b)) lst in
    combined 
    |> sort_by fst;;
val merge : ('a * 'b) list -> ('a * 'b) list -> ('a * 'b) list =
  <fun>
# merge [(1, [0]); (3, [6; 7])] [(1, [2])];;
- : (int * int list) list = [(1, [0]); (1, [2]); (3, [6; 7])]
```

**Step 3:** Group based on the key, which is easy because they're all consecutive elements in the list.

```
# let merge lst1 lst2 =
    let combined = lst1 @ lst2 in
    let sort_by f lst = List.sort (fun a b -> compare (f a) (f b)) lst in
    let group_by f lst =
      let rec aux f lst acc =
        match lst, acc with
        | [], _ -> List.rev acc
        | hd::rest, [] -> aux f rest @@ hd::acc
        | (k, v)::rest, (k', v')::rest' when k = k' -> 
            aux f rest @@ (k, v@v')::rest'
        | (k, v)::rest, _ -> aux f rest @@ (k, v)::acc
      in
      aux f lst []
    in
    combined
    |> sort_by fst
    |> group_by fst;;
val merge : ('a * 'b list) list -> ('a * 'b list) list -> ('a * 'b list) list =
  <fun>
# merge [(1, [0]); (3, [6; 7])] [(1, [2])];;
- : (int * int list) list = [(1, [2; 0]); (3, [6; 7])]
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess you're doing this to practice with list.
What I would do is store the already found keys in an accumulator

```ml
let mergePairs yourList = 
  let rec aux accKeys = function
    | [] -> []
    | x :: xs -> 
        let k,v = x in 
        if (* k in accKeys *) then aux accKeys xs (*we suppress already existing keys*)
        else (k, v @ (* get all the list of the other pairs with key = k in xs*)) :: aux (k::accKeys) xs 
  in 
  aux [] yourList;;
```

Comment: Note that `k` and `v` can be directly bound in the pattern rather than requiring a separate `let` expression.  `(k, v)::xs -> ...`